# Python find the closest larger than value in a dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, its format is like that

```
dict[num] = [<__main__.Obj instance at 0x0268A418>, 1, 5, 2]
```

I am writing a function that will receive an input, and then I will find the closest larger than value in dictionary by comparing the `dict[num][1]` and the input value. There is an example of using filter like this

```
min(filter(lambda x: x > num,li))
```

However, I don't know how to compare the input with only the `dict[num][1]` of the dictionary, and is that I must loop all elements?

Comment: can you provide a minimal example,so people can know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can consider the `bisect module`, the bisect function will return a position which closest your input value! `from bisect import bisect`